# The Radon–Nikodým theorem for vector valued measures

Tags: integration, measure-theory, banach-spaces

I am looking for a proof of the Radon–Nikodým theorem in the case of vector valued measures. Many textbooks cover the scalar case. The [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=7GUMIh6-5TYC&dq=functions%20of%20bounded%20variation%20and%20free&hl=en&ei=o7mwToKCBY_SrQeWpp1H&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA) I am reading mentions the vector valued case but does not provide a proof or a reference. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Phanindra.

Comment: One standard reference is [Diestel-Uhl](http://books.google.com/books?id=NCm4E2By8DQC).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Radon-Nikodym theorem is false in general for Banach valued measures. Banach spaces for which the RN theorem theorem holds are said to have RNP (Radon-Nikodym Property). 
For example, Hilbert spaces, reflexive space. On the other hand, $L^1$ does not have RNP.
You may check the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_property).

Answer (score 0):

Radon Nikodym theorem holds for Hilbert valued measures. A proof can be found in analysis II Serge Lang Addison Welsly 1968 or Real and functional analysis 3rd edition serge lang springer verlag 1993.
 There it is stated that a version of Radon Nikodym theprem can hold for banach spaces if one makes appropriate  definitions and the relevant research paper is cited.