# reference for conditional expectation

Tags: reference-request, probability-theory, integration, banach-spaces

Suppose $1\leq p<\infty$. Let $E$ be a Banach space. Consider a filtration  $F_n$ on some probability space $\Omega$. Let $X\in L^p(\Omega,E)$ where $L^p(\Omega,E)$ denote the Bochner space. In this case, we have

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{E}(X|F_n)=\mathbb{E}(X|F_\infty)
$$
in $L^{p}(\Omega,E)$ where $\mathbb{E}$ denote the conditional expectation operator.

I need a precise reference for this fact with a preference for a published book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Vector measures](http://books.google.com/books?id=NCm4E2By8DQC)*, Joseph Diestel, John Jerry Uhl (Chapter V *Martingales*, Section 2 *Convergence theorems*).

Comment: I took the liberty to add in a link. Verbatim the same answer (with modified parentheses) could go [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78063/radon-nikodym-theorem-for-vector-valued-measures)

Comment: @t.b. Thanks. $ $